# Multiplicar valores de uma tabela dinamica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo uma tabela dinâmica com colunas de quantidade de um produto e valor unitário, onde preciso multiplicar o valor unitário pela quantidade (qtd X val_unitario) e no final exibir o total da soma das multiplicações (conforme a imagem)

[image: table]

```js
    $('table input').on('input', function () {
                        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        var tot = 0;
                        $('input', $tr).each(function () {
                            tot += parseFloat(($(this).val()).replace(',', '.'));
                        });
                        $('td:last', $tr).text(tot);
                    }).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
       <tr id="tr_1">
          <td id="td_qtd_produto_1">
             <input type="text" id="qtd_produto_1" name="qtd_produto_1" value="5">
          </td>
          <td id="val_unitario_produto_1">
             <input type="text" id="valor_unitario_1" name="valor_unitario_1" value="48,00">
          </td>
          <td id="td_total_1">
          <p id="total_1"></p>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="tr_2">
          <td id="td_qtd_produto_2">
             <input type="text" id="qtd_produto_2" name="qtd_produto_2" value="12">
          </td>
          <td id="val_unitario_produto_2">
             <input type="text" id="valor_unitario_2" name="valor_unitario_2" value="6,80">
          </td>
          <td id="td_total_2">
          <p id="total_2"></p>
          </td>
       </tr>
      
       <tr id="td_total">
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <p id="total_geral"></p>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

Como faço para efetuar esse cálculo?
Eu estava tentando selecionar cada input via `.each()` mas não consegui entender muito bem a aplicação dele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na primeira parte do código o que ele está fazendo é colocar um evento em cada caixa de `input` dentro da tabela para quando o usuário digitar algum valor.

Nesse evento ele vai buscar a linha `tr` a qual pertence o `input` que disparou o evento e a partir dessa linha `tr` vai pegar o valor cada caixa de `input` e acumular na variavel `tot`.

No final, ele procura a coluna `td` mais à direita e colocar o valor de tot dentro dela.

Adicionei um código para buscar o valor de todas as caixas de input e não só das caixas que estão na linha corrente e depois exibir o total no campo que tem o id de total geral.

**Editado:**
O cálculo estava errado. Estava somando o valor das células quando deveria multiplicar cada linha e depois somar a coluna da direita. Ajustei para ficar correto.

```js
$('table input').on('input', function () {
   var $linha = $(this).closest('tr');
   var tot = 0
   var anterior = 1
   $linha.find('input').each(function () {
       tot = parseFloat(($(this).val()).replace(',', '.'));
       tot = (isNaN(tot) ? 0 : tot) * anterior;
       anterior = tot;
    });
    $linha.find('td:last').text(tot);
    var tg = 0;
    $linha.closest('table').find('td:last-child').each(function () {
       if ($(this).attr("id")) {
           // td sem id é a coluna do total geral, mas seria melhor ter uma identificação ou classe.
           var valor = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',', '.'));
           tg += (isNaN(valor) ? 0 : valor);
       }
    });
    $("#total_geral").text(tg);
}).trigger("input");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
           <tr id="tr_1">
              <td id="td_qtd_produto_1">
                 <input type="text" id="qtd_produto_1" name="qtd_produto_1" value="5">
              </td>
              <td id="val_unitario_produto_1">
                 <input type="text" id="valor_unitario_1" name="valor_unitario_1" value="48,00">
              </td>
              <td id="td_total_1">
              
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr id="tr_2">
              <td id="td_qtd_produto_2">
                 <input type="text" id="qtd_produto_2" name="qtd_produto_2" value="12">
              </td>
              <td id="val_unitario_produto_2">
                 <input type="text" id="valor_unitario_2" name="valor_unitario_2" value="6,80">
              </td>
              <td id="td_total_2">
              
              </td>
           </tr>
          
           <tr id="td_total">
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <p id="total_geral"></p>
              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Show de bola!
Funcionou perfeitamente, a minha maior dificuldade era entender como eu faria pra pegar o valor do primeiro input e multiplicar com o input da segunda e fazer o total.

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de somar, como está fazendo nesta linha:

```
tot += parseFloat(($(this).val()).replace(',', '.'));
```

Deveria multiplicar:

```
tot = tot * parseFloat(($(this).val()).replace(',', '.'));
```

Mas precisa também alterar o valor inicial de `tot` para `1`. Como o laço gera apenas dois índices, `0` e `1`, que são cada `input` de cada linha, quando o índice for `1` você joga o valor da multiplicação no `<p>` da última coluna da linha e soma os valores e joga no `<p>` do total geral da última linha.

**Veja o código:**

```js
$('table input').on('input', function () {
   var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
       tot = 1;
   $tr.find("input").each(function (i) {
      tot = tot * parseFloat(($(this).val()).replace(',', '.'));
      if(i == 1){
         $tr.find('td:last p').text(tot);
         
         var tg = 0;
         $tr.closest('table').find('tr p').not(":last").each(function(){
            tg += parseFloat(($(this).text()).replace(',', '.'));
         });
         
         $('#total_geral').text(tg);
      }
   });
   
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="tr_1">
       <td id="td_qtd_produto_1">
          <input type="text" id="qtd_produto_1" name="qtd_produto_1" value="5">
       </td>
       <td id="val_unitario_produto_1">
          <input type="text" id="valor_unitario_1" name="valor_unitario_1" value="48,00">
       </td>
       <td id="td_total_1">
       <p id="total_1"></p>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_2">
       <td id="td_qtd_produto_2">
          <input type="text" id="qtd_produto_2" name="qtd_produto_2" value="12">
       </td>
       <td id="val_unitario_produto_2">
          <input type="text" id="valor_unitario_2" name="valor_unitario_2" value="6,80">
       </td>
       <td id="td_total_2">
       <p id="total_2"></p>
       </td>
    </tr>
   
    <tr id="td_total">
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td>
         <p id="total_geral"></p>
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```